# Button that redirect - Android Studio Login activity

Tags: android

got the problem i wrote the Login application but finaly i've got a problem that application "Unfortunetly has stopped"

Maybe you can help what is wrong with this?

```js
package com.example.micha.notes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    Button b1,b2;
    EditText ed1,ed2;

    TextView tx1;
    int counter = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("a") &&
                        ed2.getText().toString().equals("a")) {
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(toy);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            tx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    counter--;
                    tx1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                    if (counter == 0) {
                        b1.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think that the Bug is somewhere here, but dont know what to do :(

```js
public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("a") &&
                        ed2.getText().toString().equals("a")) {
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(toy);
                }else{
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Did you add activity to the manifest?

```
Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
```

**ListActivity**?

```
<activity
        android:name=".ListActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```